# not an error (code 0) in my Moto G4 .

Tags: android

not an error(code 0) cannot open database in read/write mode. I am getting this error in my phone. I have mounted my SD card as internal storage and after few days I got this error. I am not able to download any images,music,etc. anything from any Application. It says storage is full even when it's not. Please help me.

Comment: This might be better suited in https://android.stackexchange.com/ since Stack Overflow is a community for programming questions and answers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Can you show me some of your code, where you actually try to read files?

Comment: Actually I have these problems in my android phone . Neither am I developing an Application nor I have  Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your *database doesn't exists yet or you have to create a new one*. Check if you did the following correctly:

1. Used `SQLiteOpenHelper#getWritableDatabase` [Reference.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase())
2. External storage currently mounted or not. [Reference.](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)
3. The path you provided is correct?

Comment: I have seen the things what you just wrote. Actually I have these problems in my android phone . Neither am I developing an Application nor I have Android Studio. I checked the SD card is correctly mounted. How could these problem be solved on my phone.

Comment: For that, folks at https://android.stackexchange.com/ will surely help you.